# get the mean of each value in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to get the average of the working years for each name in the HR department.

I tried this

```
work = df.loc[Employee['Department'] == 'HR', [{'Year' : 'mean'}],
                 ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'Year','Department']].drop_duplicates()
```

The result would be like this. The average values are arbitrary I did not calculate them

```
   FirstName   LastName        aver_Year   Department   
0  Joe         Faulk           3.00        HR
1  Bryce       Benton          5.00        HR
2  Sarah       Cronin          2.00        HR
3  Gabriel     Montgomery      5.00        HR
4  Patricia    Genty-Andrade   6.00        HR
```

The source dataframe

```
FirstName   LastName        Year    Department
0   Joan    Hamilton-Huber  2       HR
1   Nathan  Brigmon         5       AustinCodeDepartment
2   Shawn   Lincoln         8       HR
3   Chris   Hernandez       2       AustinConventionCenter
4   John    Montgomery      7       AustinEnergy
```

Comment: Can you provide source dataframe?

Comment: Need some clarifications for the question to make sense. (1) Is `Year` the date of joining the company? (2) How can an employee have an _average_ "years in the company"? That's just years in the company. It makes more sense to have "average years in the company by Department, for all departments or just for HR". Add add a sample of your original dataframe `df`. Use `df[:10].to_clipboard()` and paste it in the question.

Comment: @Epsi95 I have provided the source dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the group by function of pandas:

```
df_gb = df.groupby(['Department','FirstName','LastName'])['Year'].mean().reset_index()
df_gb = df_gb[df_gb['Department']=='HR']
```

The first line gives you the output you want, the average of years by department and name. Then you filter by the HR department and you obtain the data you want on the df_gb dataframe.

Comment: I edited the answer, I filter by the HR department on the last line

Comment: I tried it again, It didn't work it gave me just the year not the average

Comment: the column that has the values that you want the average is named Years or aver_year? can you give and image of the dataframe head please?

Comment: It is Year. I have edited the question and provided the source dataframe. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, so  I changed the code, instead of using aver_Year, I now use Year, this should give you the mean of values Year for each unique pair of First name and Last name, only for those in the HR department

Answer (score 0):

First, you can select only the items related to the HR department:

`df = df[df['Department'] == 'HR']`

After that, you can group by Name, Surname and ask for the average of the column Year as follows

`work = df.groupby(['FirstName', 'LastName'])['Year'].mean()`

Eventually, you can rename the column Year to aver_Year by doing

`work.rename(columns={'Year':'aver_Year'}, inplace=True)`

Comment: It didn't work it gave me just the year not the average.